# Fail to train models through Microsoft Custom Translator platform

Tags: microsoft-translator

I have tried to train customized models several times for language pair English-German of category Technology, but all got ***Trainingfailed*** status

FYI: [Training Status Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxU8v.jpg)

From "Training Details", it seems sentences alignment works well. And there is no explicit error message found.

FYI: [Training Details Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx2Sr.jpg)

Is there any suggestion about solving this problem?

Thanks very much.

Comment: It's successful to use the same data-clean script and procedure to generate a model for language pair English-Spanish. I suppose it's most likely to be a backend NMT system issue. Need Custom Translator support team's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were experiencing a transient issue in our training environment that has now been resolved.  Please retry your training and it should succeed.

Comment: The training is successful now. Thanks for your help.